# Should I move class methods to prototype?

Tags: javascript, performance, prototype

I have class

```
function Foo(a) {
  this.a = a;
  this.bar = function () {
    console.log(this.a);
  };
  this.buz = function () {
    this.a();
    console.log('bzz');
  };
}
```

and I'll have quite many instances of this class. Should I move methods to prototype?

```
function Foo(a) {
  this.a = a;
}
Foo.prototype = {
  bar: function () {
    console.log(this.a);
  },
  buz: function () {
    this.a();
    console.log('bzz');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This will save on memory as each method will be `shared` instead of recreated each time you instantiate the class.

Methods inside the constructor are considered `privileged methods` as they can have access to `private variables` inside the constructor and should only be used if you need access to a private variable.

[Crockford on privileged methods](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html)

Answer (score 1):

Putting class methods is a good idea to save memory. There will be only one instance of the method in the prototype instead of many instances in each object.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to define methods inside of a constructor in JS is to create a "[Privileged](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html)" method.

The idea is to create a method that is publicly available, but has access to the private instance variables.